# The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy, invalidoperationexception

I've tested it with and without explicit conversion in the datatable columns, but it kept throwing me the exception System.InvalidOperationException.

FYI, those columns with typeof(string) are all nvarchar in my database. I'm passing in a List called **test** which is of a user-defined type.

I wasn't going to use sqlbulkcopy initially, but ever since porting over to azure database, I need a faster insertion query.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```cs
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("LinkID", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("RoadName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("RoadCategory", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("SpeedBand");
dt.Columns.Add("MinimumSpeed", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("MaximumSpeed", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("StartLatitude");
dt.Columns.Add("StartLongitude");
dt.Columns.Add("EndLatitude");
dt.Columns.Add("EndLongitude");
dt.Columns.Add("Distance", typeof(string));

for (int i = 0; i < test.Count; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(test[i].LinkID, test[i].RoadName, test[i].RoadCategory, 
       test[i].SpeedBand, test[i].MinimumSpeed, test[i].MaximumSpeed, 
       test[i].StartLatitude, test[i].StartLongitude, test[i].EndLatitude, 
       test[i].EndLongitude, test[i].Distance);
}

string sqlConnectionString = "//secret";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
    }

    using (var sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
    {
        //sqlBulk.BatchSize = 1000;
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "dbo.TrafficSpeedBands";

        try
        {
            // Write from the source to the destination.
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably your database column size is lesser. Use nvarchar(max),
eg,Your column is nvarchar(100) and you are trying to insert string with 200 characters

Comment: Whats the underlying db's type of `Speedband`,  `Startlatitude`, etc. fields? Are they all `nvarchar`?

Comment: @InBetween they are int and float

Comment: @Atk i don't tink that's the case. previously i was using single insert statements and there was no problem. the only downside is it takes too long. hence, i switched over to using datatable and sqlbulkcopy. but now this error pops up

Answer (score 0):

i've switched to using a dataAdapter and it works now

```
string sqlConnectionString = "//secret";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(e);
                }
                Debug.WriteLine("Connection opened");
                var table = new DataTable();

                // read the table structure from the database
                using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT TOP 0 * FROM dbo.TrafficSpeedBands", conn))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(table);
                };

                Debug.WriteLine("Filling in rows");
                for (var i = 0; i < test.Count; i++)
                {
                    var row = table.NewRow();
                    row["LinkID"] = test[i].LinkID;
                    row["RoadName"] = test[i].RoadName;
                    row["RoadCategory"] = test[i].RoadCategory;
                    row["SpeedBand"] = test[i].SpeedBand;
                    row["MinimumSpeed"] = test[i].MinimumSpeed;
                    row["MaximumSpeed"] = test[i].MaximumSpeed;
                    row["StartLatitude"] = test[i].StartLatitude;
                    row["StartLongitude"] = test[i].StartLongitude;
                    row["EndLatitude"] = test[i].EndLatitude;
                    row["EndLongitude"] = test[i].EndLongitude;
                    row["Distance"] = test[i].Distance;

                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }

                using (var sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Ready to load live");
                    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "dbo.TrafficSpeedBands";

                    try
                    {
                        // Write from the source to the destination.
                        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(table);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }                                        

                    Debug.WriteLine("Done");
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
//...
dt.Columns.Add("SpeedBand");
//...
dt.Columns.Add("StartLatitude");
dt.Columns.Add("StartLongitude");
dt.Columns.Add("EndLatitude");
dt.Columns.Add("EndLongitude");
```

By default, the method `Add(string columnName)`  will add a column of type `string`. You therefore have a type mismatch with the underlying db table and the bulk copy fails. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumncollection.add?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataColumnCollection_Add_System_String_) for more details.

Your solution with `DataAdapter` works because the adapter reads the schema of the underyling table and sets up the `DataTable` with compatible types for you.